# MySQL for statistical results

Tags: mysql, sql, average, median, standard-deviation

I have a big task that I need some help with.

My goal is the following table structure:

[image]

**type**: type of car
**number_of_cars**: number of cars for each car type
**number**: number of people driving each car type
**average**: average number of people driving each car type
**median**: number of people driving each car type
**max**: max value of people driving each car type
**min**: min value of people driving each car type
**standard deviation**: standard deviation of number of people driving each car type

My data table looks like the following:

```html
id    type      people
-----------------------
1     subaru    1
2     bmw       5
3     tesla     2
4     tesla     3
5     subaru    4
6     tesla     1
7     tesla     3
8     subaru    1
9     bmw       5
10    subaru    7
11    subaru    7
12    ford      2
13    ford      4
14    subaru    6
15    ford      3
16    tesla     2
17    tesla     1
18    tesla     1
19    tesla     1
```

Where id is a unique identifier, type is the type of car, and people is the number of people driving this car.

How do I create one giant MySQL query that gives me the results I need for my table?

Help is appreciated!

Ps. I know that MySQL is not necessarily the best approach to gather statictical data like this, but it should be possible, right?

Comment: . . Are you familiar with `group by`?  Almost everything you want to calculate is easily handled by an aggregation query.

Answer (score 0):

All data the statistical data you want can be gathered using `GROUP BY` statement and built-in functions of mysql. Simply read about [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in mysql.

Only thing you won't find there is median. Mysql doesn't have built-in function for that but you can easily find some way to do that just by googling it